# ARDUINO, LCD or I2c Display. Printing a number countdown (10 to 0) on the same cursor position without the appearing numbers overlapping themselves

Tags: c++, arduino

I used a for loop function to countdown numbers from 10 to 0. The output is to be printed on an i2c Oled display. The code works! it presents the output (counting numbers) on the same cursor position as I desired. But the numbers overlap each other, they never go back(disappear after showing up). like, (After the first number which is 10 appears, then nine shows up overlapping the 10 and then 8 shows up overlapping 10 and 9 and then 7 shows up overlapping 10, 9 and 8 and the 6 shows up overlapping all the previous numbers. in the end the digit pixel is populated into dots. How can I make each number to disappear just after showing up in order to make room for the next number simultaneously/instantly without delay is such transition, just as in the case of a digital clock?

This is my code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

void setup() {
display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop() {

for (int i=9; i>0; i--){
display.setTextSize(2);
display.setTextColor(WHITE);
display.setCursor(45,10);
display.println(i);
display.display();
  delay(1000);
}


}
```

Comment: Two thoughts... reprint the same number, but in BLACK color, to erase it. Or clear the field first, by printing two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The Adafruit_SSD1306 library includes a function to draw a horizontal line.  A suggestion would be to use that function to *clear* the previously drawn characters.

```
void Adafruit_SSD1306::drawFastHLine(int16_t x, int16_t y, int16_t w,
                                     uint16_t color);
```

From the library:

drawFastHLine() - Draw a horizontal line.

- x:            Leftmost column -- 0 at left to (screen width - 1) at right.
- y:            Row of display -- 0 at top to (screen height -1) at bottom.
- w:            Width of line, in pixels.
- color:        Line color, one of: SSD1306_BLACK, SSD1306_WHITE or SSD1306_INVERSE.
- return: None (void)

Note:   Changes buffer contents only, no immediate effect on display.
Follow up with a call to display(), or with other graphics
commands as needed by one's own application.